# At pixel-level, remove all the pixels at the boundary between copy-move forgery areas and background from F-measure calculation?

Tags: image, performance, image-processing, computer-forensics

i work in copy move forgery localization, i need to measure the F-score, I have the output map and ground-truth image, but the results don't agree with existing papers results. In one of these papers, the author said, "At pixel-level, we remove all the pixels at the boundary between copy-move forgery areas and background from F-measure calculation". I don't know what that mean and how can be done with Matlab?
Can anyone help me on this?

```
function [tpr,fpr,acc,fs]=calculate_statis(technique_binary_image, ground_truth)
technique_binary_image = technique_binary_image./255.0;
ground_truth = ground_truth./255.0;
false_positives=0;
false_negatives=0;
true_positives=0;
true_negatives=0;
totalClone = 0;
totalNormal = 0;
 for i=1:size(technique_binary_image,1)
 for j=1:size(technique_binary_image,2) 
    if technique_binary_image(i,j)==ground_truth(i,j) && ground_truth(i,j)~=0
        true_positives=true_positives+1;
    end
            if technique_binary_image(i,j)==ground_truth(i,j) && ground_truth(i,j)==0
        true_negatives=true_negatives+1;
    end
    if technique_binary_image(i,j)~=ground_truth(i,j) && ground_truth(i,j)~=0
        false_negatives=false_negatives+1;
    end
    if technique_binary_image(i,j)~=ground_truth(i,j) && ground_truth(i,j)==0
        false_positives=false_positives+1;
    end
    if ground_truth(i,j)~=0
        totalClone = totalClone + 1;
    end
    if ground_truth(i,j)==0
        totalNormal = totalNormal + 1;
    end
end
end
tpr=(true_positives)/totalClone;
fpr=(false_positives)/totalNormal;
acc = (tpr + (1 - fpr))/2;
pres=(true_positives)/(true_positives + false_positives);
%fs=2*tpr*pres/(pres + tpr);
 %fs=(2*tpr)/(tpr+fpr+1);
fs=(2*true_positives)/((2*true_positives)+false_positives+false_negatives);

end
```

paper link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1047320321000365

Comment: you should contact the author of the paper. they surely know what they meant. nobody else is better equipped to help you.

Comment: i asked them, but i didn't receive an answer.

Comment: why didn't you link to the paper you're discussing? -- [tour], [ask]

Comment: ah, nice. my uni subscribes to a lot but strangely not that. no matter, that's publicly funded research (and from the People's Republic) so, hippety hoppety, imaginary property https://sci-hub.ru/10.1016/j.jvcir.2021.103068

Answer (score 0):

> We chose F-measure for evaluating all the methods.
>
> (formula 34)
>
> At pixel-level, we remove all the pixels at the boundary between copy-move forgery areas and background from F-measure calculation.

In the section containing that quote, they discuss evaluation metrics. They don't "remove". They "exclude from consideration" those pixels that are *not clearly* either inside the forgery or not, i.e. those on boundaries between background and forgery. Those are uncertain and hard to classify well. Those algorithms were intended to be evaluated on finding the forgery, not delineating the area exactly.

Comment: Could you give guidelines on how to implement that on Matlab?  @Christoph Rackwitz

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. you are responsible for getting started. you don't have _any_ code yet. did you honestly think anyone would just implement a paper for you?

Comment: I have a code and it work, the problem in Fscore measurement, the available functions for Fscore results doesn't agree with the papers results.

Comment: did you ask for help with your code? if yes, why did you not present it yet? if not, that must mean you do want people to write entirely new code from that paper. -- please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: I attached the code i used for metrics calculation. Is there is something wrong on it?